# In Aspose, when exporting document to html, how can I access multiple images in stream

Tags: html, image, export, aspose

When I use Aspose.Word to export a .docx with multiple images into html, I can save those images into MemoryStream, for example, I can use IImageSavingCallback as

```
    var imagesStream = new MemoryStream();
    var handleImageSaving = new HandleImageSaving(imagesStream);    
    options.ImageSavingCallback = handleImageSaving;        
    document.Save(stream, options);


    public class HandleImageSaving : IImageSavingCallback
    {
        private MemoryStream m_images;

        public HandleImageSaving(
            MemoryStream i_images)
        {
            m_images = i_images;
        }
        void IImageSavingCallback.ImageSaving(ImageSavingArgs args)
        {
            args.ImageStream = m_images;
            args.KeepImageStreamOpen = true;  
        }
    }
```

After .Save is executed, multiple images are stored in imagesStream, now I need to retrieve image one by one from imagesStream, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the following sample:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"input.docx");

MemoryStream htmlStream = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream imagesStream = new MemoryStream();

HtmlSaveOptions options = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html);
var handleImageSaving = new HandleImageSaving(imagesStream);
options.ImageSavingCallback = handleImageSaving;

doc.Save(htmlStream, options);

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder();
foreach (Stream imgStream in handleImageSaving.ImageStreams)
{
    builder.InsertImage(imgStream);
    builder.Writeln();
}

builder.Document.Save(MyDir + @"15.12.0.docx");
```

And the definition of HandleImageSaving class is as follows

```
public class HandleImageSaving : IImageSavingCallback
{
    public ArrayList ImageStreams;
    private MemoryStream m_images;

    public HandleImageSaving(MemoryStream i_images)
    {
        ImageStreams = new ArrayList();
        m_images = i_images;
    }
    void IImageSavingCallback.ImageSaving(ImageSavingArgs args)
    {
        Shape shape = (Shape)args.CurrentShape;
        m_images = new MemoryStream(shape.ImageData.ImageBytes);
        ImageStreams.Add(m_images);

        args.ImageStream = m_images;
        args.KeepImageStreamOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: The idea works, but sometime, for some reason, even for a image, the shape.ImageData is null, so simply using m_images = new MemoryStream() will work, thanks Awais!